# OpenJFX 11 Raspberry Pi Touchscreen No Touch

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

The facts:

- Raspberry PI 3B+
- OpenJFX 11
- 10" Touchscreen D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd
- App is running and you see everything you want but...
- **No Touchevents**

From my research, that doesn't seem like a nice problem.
Now my question is: How do I debug the problem at all? Is there a workaround?

Maybe there is a tutorial for all this theme? Does somebody know, whether gluon mobile embedded supports raspi/touchscreen?

Comment: Do you use `sudo` to launch your app? Mouse events require some admin rights. You should see some errors on the console about this?

Comment: @JoséPereda Thats one crazy point. There are no errors in the console - I see everything in the console, but no errors.

Comment: Any progress? I had once a touchscreen that required an extra USB connection to enable touch events, can you verify that?

Comment: @JoséPereda Hey José. Thats right. The USB connection is plugged and it works for the whole system, but not for the jfx frame. I'm trying to read the events via `processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "evtest /dev/input/event0");` I think that will work quit well, but firing the mouseclicked events not working yet.

Comment: Make sure you use `sudo` before you launch the java command.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you. You were right.

Answer (score 1):

I had a wrong jdk setup for the raspberry. I think that was the problem, because after installing the bellsoft [jdk/jfx](https://download.bell-sw.com/java/11.0.2/bellsoft-jdk11.0.2-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb) it worked and there appeared the errors which José Pereda mentioned.